# Java GSON deserializing array of objects

Tags: java, json, gson

Im trying to deserialize a JSON string into an array of objects looking like this:

```
[{"ParentLocationName":null
,"Id":"String-Id"
,"Name":"String-Name"
,"ExternalId":null
,"LocationType":0
,"TimeZone":null
,"ParentLocationId":null}
,{"ParentLocationName":"String-Name"
,"Id":"String-Id2"
,"Name":"Child-Name"
,"ExternalId":null
,"LocationType":0
,"TimeZone":null
,"ParentLocationId":"String-Id"}
,{"ParentLocationName":null
,"Id":"String-Id3"
,"Name":"Some other name"
,"ExternalId":null
,"LocationType":0
,"TimeZone":null
,"ParentLocationId":null}]
```

so I have a class called Location with corresponding fields:

```
public class Location {

    public String ParentLocationName;
    public String Id;
    public String Name;
    public String ExternalId;
    public int LocationType;
    public String TimeZone;
    public String ParentLocationId;
}
```

Where I am using Gson in the following way:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Location[] places = gson.fromJson(Json_As_String, Location[].class);
```

and I am receiving error:

```
Expected a string but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 3 path $[0]
```

Ive also tried using a collection like so:

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<>
Type colType = new TypeToken<Collection<Location>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Location> locs = gson.fromJson(Json_As_String,colType );
```

But receiving the same error.

Comment: For me this code is working fine. Are you using the exact string that you mentioned in the question?

Comment: Yes, I am using the exact string as given above

Comment: I am using gson as a maven dependency at version 2.8.1

Comment: I cant reproduce this crash with this version and string.

Comment: can you post the complete stacktrace ? maybe it helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148757/discussion-between-krish-and-jonaswg).

Comment: The error was related to some obscure library being imported in place of my own after refactoring folders and class names...